# Dissolve ArcGIS Pro Python doesn't take string variable for field list

Tags: arcpy, python, dissolve, list, string

I try to dissolve layer having multiple fields statistics calculated. I prepared a string variable which has all the information in it. When I paste printed variable into dissolve it works. However I'm not able to use the variable itself.
EDIT: `OutFields` is string.

Variable:

```
print(OutFields)
[[Fields_i[0], "SUM"],[Fields_i[1], "SUM"],[Fields_i[2], "SUM"],[Fields_i[3], "SUM"],[Fields_i[4], "SUM"],[Fields_i[5], "SUM"],[Fields_i[6], "SUM"],[Fields_i[7], "SUM"]]
```

It works this way:

```
arcpy.Dissolve_management(IntPolygon, OutPolygon, ToID, [[Fields_i[0], "SUM"],[Fields_i[1], "SUM"],[Fields_i[2], "SUM"],[Fields_i[3], "SUM"],[Fields_i[4], "SUM"],[Fields_i[5], "SUM"],[Fields_i[6], "SUM"],[Fields_i[7], "SUM"]], "", "")
```

And it doesn't this way:

```
arcpy.Dissolve_management(IntPolygon, OutPolygon, ToID, OutFields, "", "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works when you pass a list of lists
`[[Fields_i[0], "SUM"],[...`

But not with a string representation of a list of lists:

```
"[[Fields_i[0], "SUM"],[F.." #Fields_i[0] inside a string wont work/fetch correct fieldname.
```

Then pass a list of lists. Try something like this:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\somedb.gdb\somedata'

Fields_i = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(dataset=fc)] #Or whatever way you list your fields

OutFields = [[Fields_i[j], "SUM"] for j in range(0,8)]
```

Then dissolve

```
arcpy.Dissolve_management(IntPolygon, OutPolygon, ToID, OutFields, "", "")
```